# Reset 2013 Apps as Default

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-office

I am running Windows 8.1 Enterprise and (usually) Office 2013.

Recently I ran into an old access file that required Office 2007 to run. I found the Office 2007 disk and chose to only install Access 2007 with all other apps being installed on first use (under the assumption I would never have to use them).

However, now when I open a file in (say) Excel by double clicking the file, instead of launching Excel then opening the file from the Open menu, my computer tries to install Excel 2007 (presumably because I installed Office 2007 second).

I have tried right clicking a file associated with excel, opening the properties window and navigating to the Excel 2013 executable in the "Default Program" file menu, but then when I try to open the file I get a "This app can't run on your PC" message.

What should I do?

Comment: "an old access file that required Office 2007" There's nothing that's 2007-compatible that won't run as-is in 2013 - at least nothing I've ever seen or heard of.  But regardless, try uninstalling Office 2007 and run a repair on the Office 2013 install. And/or try using a System Restore point and go back to a point before you installed Office 2007.

Comment: @techie007 Access 2013 dropped support for ADP files.

Comment: Ahh well there ya go.  But regardless, try the standard stuff -- uninstall Office 2007, repair Office 2013 -- help any?  Use system restore to go back to before you installed Office 2007 -- help any? :)

Comment: @techie007 Probably. I'm going to hold out a bit longer to see if there is an alternative to nuking this thing though. The uninstall is going to be one of my last resorts. 2013 still *works* I just have to open all files directly from the apps.

Comment: Have you tried using the Default Program control panel applet to reset them (instead of the right-click Open With... chooser)? How about JUST running the Office 2013 repair (which should fix associations)?

Comment: @techie007 Your last comment got me thinking about doing that. I am going to give that a shot. If you will post that an an answer, and it works, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @techie007 The repair worked.